# Find sum of right and left hand of list element in python

Tags: python

Is there any way for compare sum of left and right of a selected element in a list?
For example:

```
li = [2,3,0,9,6]
if selected item is '0', I want to compare sum of 2,3 and 9,6
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the selection really `0` or is it `li[2]` (i.e., is the the value, or the position in the list that is selected)?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: How is left/right defined? What would be the comp. for `li = [1, 2, 1]` ?

Comment: @JonClements we have to compare all of list elements.

Comment: What happens if there's `[2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0]` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
li = [2,3,0,9,6]
```

If you are given `0` (or any number):

```
n = 0
i = li.index(n)     # returns the first location of n (0 in your case)
left = li[:i]       # gives the left part of the list
right = li[i+1:]    #     and the right part
lsum = sum(left)
rsum = sum(right)
```

But you must be careful because `.index` returns the *first* instance of the item.  If you had more than one `0` it would split the list at the *first* `0`.

If you're given its position, just start with `i` from above without searching.

```
i = 2
left = sum(li[:i])
right = sum(li[i+1:])
```

Note that I've combined the last two rows together, taking the sum without saving the separate lists.

Then, you can compare `left` and `right` however you wish.

Comment: +1 It would also be nice to handle the exception in case 0 is not in the list.

Comment: @jurgenreza OK I'll make it clear that the zero can be changed.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a `partition` which is a single value that can be used to `split` the input, then - similar to askewchan's answer, but can take any arbitrary iterable, and not one that requires being able to index (note this is an abuse of `lambda`):

```
li = [2,3,0,9,6]

from itertools import takewhile
print (lambda L=iter(li): sum(takewhile(lambda e: e != 0, L)) == sum(L))()
# False
```

**more sensible way**:

```
def partitions_equal(iterable, at):
    i = iter(iterable)
    return sum(iter(i.next, at)) == sum(i)
```

Comment: As you say, this is an abuse of lambda, and the only thing it gains is turning 3 lines into 2, so… why not just write it the pythonic way, with `L=iter(li)` on one line, and the comparison on the next line?

Comment: @abarnert more sensible answer posted

Comment: The "more sensible way" doesn't do the same thing as the "abuse of lambda" way. It's worth showing both and explaining the difference (one takes a value, the other an index)—and it's also worth writing both without abusing lambda.